Divided brain thought experiment: what is an analog of Born rule in biology?
Consider the following thoght experiment: your brain is divided in two and then each part is inserted in new body and regenerated (using future medicine), including all memories being restored. So, now there are two people derived from one.
Then one of the resulting people is given a billion dollars while the other one is imprisoned for life. Does the game worth it?
What if the brain is divided not in half but unevenly? What's the probability that you would find yourself as the one to be imprisoned after the experiment? For instance, if only a small piece of brain is cut off and the bigger part after recovery is given money, the game seems worth it. But what hapens if the cut piece is big?
I think, this thought experiment is analoguous to the split of the observer in many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, but what rule plays the role of the Born rule here?
Notice that here seemingly no quantum mechanics is involved, yet an analog of Born rule still should be present. Can it be concluded that some analog of Born rule should be present in all fields that somehow involve split or copying of consciousness, such as mind uploading, etc?

Why do you think that Born rule is relevant here?

Some (most) of brain's functions are localized: if you split the barin in two parts, the two half-barins will not work properly: one of the two "zombies" will have sight but will not be able to speak and vice-versa...

In MWI, the probability is proportional to the share of worlds where the event in question happens, and those never interact with each other afterwards. So this is not analogous to it at all, and the probability question makes little sense, let alone the Born rule.

@MauroALLEGRANZA the experiment discusses the case where the both parts are completely regenerated.

@Conifold so, under what conditions it is worth to play this game? Say, if only 10% of the brain is cut off, would it be worth?

If everything is regenerated what difference does the percentage make? Worth to whom, according to what payoff?

@Conifold as stated in the description of the experiment one of the regenerated parts is given 1 billion dollars while the other one is imprisoned for life.

What is stated in the description is quite useless for either making sense of probability or of the "worth", as the original "player" ceases to be relevant. The two issues are also unrelated to each other in your scenario as currently described, so it needs major fixing on both fronts to become intelligible.

@Conifold what do you do not understand? A brain is divided into two parts and the future medicine can regenerate the both parts completely. So we have TWO people produced from original one. Then one of the resulting persons is given 1 billion dollars, the other one is imprisoned for life. The question is: under what circumstances a reasonable person should agree to participate in this game and what probability for him to end up in a prison cell or as a billionaire? Evidently, if only a small piece of brain is cut off and the bigger part after recovery is given money, the game is worth it.

@Anixx But the original person ceases to exist. So worth it to who? This makes no sense.

@Stella what do you mean by "original person ceases to exist"? If a part of your brain is taken out but the rest regenerated, do you cease to exist?

But each part is regenerated. Some of those parts will win. Others will lose. And to answer your question directly, there’s no answer to that. You can identify with however many people you like. I suppose it depends on your memories and your sense of identity. But one thing is for sure. There will be multiple conscious experiences, not just one. So the question has no understandable answer

Can you restate the title as a question?

Brain doesn't exist. "Brain" is just an idea in consciousness. See my paper "How Self-Reference Builds the World": https://philpeople.org/profiles/cosmin-visan

Let me reduce this problem to a simpler yet equivalent one - consider the following thought experiment: You toss a fair coin. If it comes up heads you are given a billion dollars otherwise you are imprisoned for life. Is this game worth it?
Indeed it is not about the mind boggling problem of personal identity anymore, but it never really was.

When you throw a coin, it has probability of 1/2 to land on each side. But what happens with probabilities if the brain is divided not in half but into unequal parts? In extreme case, only one neuron is taken from the brain, in this case it seems worth to play if the bigger brain part is given the money (but the neuron is regenerated to become a full brain and goes to prison).

Brain doesn't exist. "Brain" is just an idea in consciousness. See my paper "How Self-Reference Builds the World": https://philpeople.org/profiles/cosmin-visan


The no-cloning theorem forbids cloning of information on the
quantum level. In the light of this theorem speculations like
copying of consciousness and mind uploading seem rather
questionable.
Sperry’s  analysis of split-brain patients showed that the two
halfs of the human brain are not functional equivalent. Split brain
patients are persons with the neural connections between the left
and the right half of the cortex being cut. Before continuing
with thought experiments like the OP’s question one should study the
reports how a person with split brain experiences his/her
self-consciousness.
The Born rule is a simple rule how to obtain the probability as the
modulus of the square of the probability amplitude. One of Born’s
important ideas was to propose the probability interpretation of the
psi-function, quite a different caliber, see Born rule.


I can tell how the halves of the brain in the brain-split experiments report: the both halves consider themselves as the original person and not a half-brain. They do not even notice that they are impaired and cannot control one limb. On the other hand, the brain split is not complete in those experiments, as it is only the cortex which is divided. It is possible that the qualia remains non-split and only motor and reasoning functions get affected.

@Anixx Did you doublecheck your statements about the two halves of the cortex againt the first-hand reports of split-brain patients? Do these reports confirm your statements? - A person is no longer alive after splitting the whole brain completely. - Does neuroscience confirm your opinion about the continuity of qualia after a complete brain split? Any references?

There are two kinds of such experiments: one is when the corpus callosum (the tissue that commects the hemispheres) is cut off, it is permanent, the other one is when one of the hemispheres is temporarily disabled with substances. In both cases the patient remains alive. As to continuity of qualia, it is impossible to tell with scientific methods, like neuroscience as it involves hard problem of consciousness. Neither the reports of the patients can help here. Hence my question: it seems, one can infer the result regarding qualia from analogy with quantum mechanics (MWI)

A link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain

Brain doesn't exist. "Brain" is just an idea in consciousness. See my paper "How Self-Reference Builds the World": https://philpeople.org/profiles/cosmin-visan

There is no meaningful analogy with the Born rule. The rule rises because of a very specific property of wave functions in quantum theory, namely that a valid wave function can be expressed as an expansion over the eigenfunctions of an observable operator. The probability of a wave function changing to become one of those eigenfunctions as the result of a measurement is related to the extent to which that eigenfunction is present in the expansion of the wave function.
To make that a little clearer, suppose the wave function is W and the eigenfunctions of a given observable operator are E1, E2, E3..., then you can express W as a sum of the form of a% of E1, plus b% of E2, plus c% of E3 etc etc etc, potentially over a huge number of Es (in practice the expansion tends to converge to W with relatively few components of E included in the mix). If E5, say, is 23% weighted in the mix of Es that make up W, then that determines the likelihood of W changing to become E5 after a measurement. That is what the Born rule is about.
In your brain thought experiment, there is absolutely nothing comparable to the expansion of wave functions in terms of orthogonal eigenfunctions, so there is no reason whatsoever to assume the Born rule is remotely applicable.

Brain doesn't exist. "Brain" is just an idea in consciousness. See my paper "How Self-Reference Builds the World": https://philpeople.org/profiles/cosmin-visan
